# Evaluating an Integral with a Dot Product

Tags: multivariable-calculus, line-integrals, electromagnetism

Lets say I have

> $\int{ \overrightarrow{B} \cdot\ \overrightarrow{dA} }$

is that equal to

> $ \int{ B \cdot dA } \cdot\cos(\theta)$

or

> $\int{(B \cdot\cos(\theta)) \cdot dA} $

For example: a magnetic flux on a rotating surface, where the magnetic field is uniform and the area vector is rotating.

In the case where the $\cos(\theta)$ is inside the integral, theta is changing, so the integral wants to see the theta put into terms of A or the other way around;
Whereas in the case where $\cos(\theta)$ is outside of the integral, B is uniform (constant with respect to space) can be pulled out, and the integral(dA) can be evaluated as A therefore $\Phi_B = BA\cos(\theta)$.

Edit: In the example $\theta$ is known- such as a rotating solenoid where the angle between the magnetic vector and the normal vector of the surface area lie in the same plane. Ex: $\theta = \omega \cdot t$ and both $\omega$ and t are known.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/104041) :)

Comment: @Shaun Edited. Thanks.

Comment: You're welcome, but please use it *throughout*. Use `$\cos(x)$` for $\cos(x)$, because `$cos(x)$` gives $cos(x)$, which means $c\times o\times s(x)$.

Comment: The $\cos\theta$ can never be outside of the integral, right? The dot product is inside the integral.

Answer (score -1):

This type of integral is known as a line integral. Here is the process by which you would go about this type of problem.

Suppose we are given some vector field $F:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^n$ and some path $\gamma$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$. The line integral will tell us how much the path lines up with the vector field. In physics, this is often used for summing up a force field along the path, yielding the energy gained by traveling along that path. Now, we look at the line integral:

$$\int_\gamma F\cdot \mathrm{d}r$$

Note that $\mathrm{d}r=\begin{pmatrix}\mathrm{d}x^1\\\mathrm{d}x^2\\\vdots\\\mathrm{d}x^n\end{pmatrix}$.

This is summing up the projections of $F$ onto $\gamma$ across all of $\gamma$. Now, we parameterize $r$ as $r:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}^n$ such that $r([0,1])=\gamma$, and denote this parameterization as $r(t)$. Note that this means all the components of $r(t)$ are functions of $t$. Now, by the multivariable chain rule:

$$\mathrm{d}r=r'(t)\hspace{1mm}\mathrm{d}t$$

Thus:

$$\int_\gamma F\cdot \mathrm{d}r=\int_0^1F(r(t))\cdot r'(t)\hspace{1mm}\mathrm{d}t$$

Which can then be solved using standard single variable calc techniques.

**EDIT**

The process described above is for a line integral, however, in the OP's question, the integral given was a surface integral.

Suppose we are given some force field $F:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^3$ and either a $2$-cell or $3$-cell $A$ (a subset of $\mathbb{R}^3$ whose topological interior is diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{B}^2$ or $\mathbb{B}^3$ resp.). Then, the surface integral of $F$ over $A$ is defined to be:

$$\int_AF\cdot\hat{n}\hspace{1mm}\mathrm{d}s$$

Let's break this down, both intuitively and rigorously.

*INTUITIVELY*

We are summing up the magnitude of the parts of $F$ normal to $A$. The $F\cdot\hat{n}\hspace{1mm}\mathrm{d}s$ part of the integral is the inner product of $F$ with the unit vector normal to $\mathrm{d}s$, where $\mathrm{d}s$ is a small, "flat" piece of $A$. The $\int_A$ means we are summing up these magnitudes across the entire $2$-cell $A$.

*RIGOROUSLY*

We then define a smooth parameterization of $A$: $a(u,v):I\times I\to\mathbb{R}^3$, which has the property $a(I\times I)=A$. Now, we can define what we mean by $\hat{n}\hspace{1mm}\mathrm{d}s$ by using the cross product and a type of mapping called a differential $2$-form (basically a way of representing area):

$$\hat{n}\hspace{1mm}\mathrm{d}s=\frac{\frac{\partial a}{\partial u}\times\frac{\partial a}{\partial v}}{||\frac{\partial a}{\partial u}\times\frac{\partial a}{\partial v}||}\hspace{1mm}\mathrm{d}u\wedge\mathrm{d}v=\frac{\frac{\partial a}{\partial u}\times\frac{\partial a}{\partial v}}{||\frac{\partial a}{\partial u}\times\frac{\partial a}{\partial v}||}\hspace{1mm}\mathrm{d}u\hspace{1mm}\mathrm{d}v$$

Thus, our surface integral may be written:

$$\int_AF\cdot\hat{n}\hspace{1mm}\mathrm{d}s=\int_0^1\int_0^1F\cdot\frac{\frac{\partial a}{\partial u}\times\frac{\partial a}{\partial v}}{||\frac{\partial a}{\partial u}\times\frac{\partial a}{\partial v}||}\hspace{1mm}\mathrm{d}u\hspace{1mm}\mathrm{d}v$$

There are then a couple of theorems that can help to solve this:

**GAUSS'S THEOREM**

Suppose that $A$ is a $3$-cell. Then, $\partial A$ is diffeomorphic to the sphere $\mathbb{S}^2$ (this is to help with intuition), and:

$$\int_{\partial A}F\cdot\hat{n}\hspace{1mm}\mathrm{d}s=\int_A\text{div}\hspace{.5mm}F\hspace{1mm}\mathrm{d}V$$

**STOKES'S THEOREM**

Suppose that $A$ is a $2$-cell. Then:

$$\int_A\text{curl}\hspace{.5mm}F\cdot\hat{n}\hspace{1mm}\mathrm{d}s=\int_{\partial A}F\cdot\mathrm{d}r$$

Where we can solve this line integral in the way explained above.

**CONCLUSION**

The reason we do not use $F\cdot\hat{n}\hspace{1mm}\mathrm{d}s=(\cos\theta)\hspace{.5mm}|F|\hspace{.5mm}|\hat{n}\hspace{1mm}\mathrm{d}s|$ is because we do not know the angle between the tangent space at that point and the field $F$. Additionally, there is not much meaning to $|\hat{n}\hspace{1mm}\mathrm{d}s|=|\hat{n}|\hspace{.5mm}|\mathrm{d}s|=|\mathrm{d}s|$, as $\mathrm{d}s$ is a differential representing a tiny bit of area.

Comment: The integral that the OP is describing is NOT an line integral.  Rather, it is a surface integral with the term $\overrightarrow{dA}=\hat n\,dA$, where $\hat n$ is the unit normal to the surface that is oriented according to the right-hand rule.  So, your answer needs to be modified accordingly.

Comment: This is not addressing the issues at hand. Plenty of surfaces are not boundaries and, even for those that are, plenty of force fields are not acceptable for the Divergence Theorem. Your generalized Stokes’s Theorem does not belong here. What does is a discussion of the definition of surface integrals. Besides, did you even think about the gist of the original question? It was about $\cos\theta$, although OP didn’t say what the angle is.

Comment: See edits that were made

Comment: The example is about evaluating faraday's law for a rotating solenoid in a uniform magnetic field. $\theta$ is known. I was under the impression that when there's a variable term inside an integral you have to put it in terms of the differential the integral is being evaluated against. The formula given for the magnetic flux was $B \cdot A \cdot \cos{ \theta }$ but I didn't understand how $\int{ \overrightarrow{ B } \cdot \hat{n} dA }$ evaluated to that if theta was changing. I was under the impression. That you can't just pull out $\cos{ \theta }$like that if $\theta$ isn't constant.

Comment: Oh gotcha. Yeah, I think you’d have to write $\theta$ as a function of your position (or parameterization). I haven’t seen it done that way before, but if you did know exactly how $\theta$ was changing then you could use that version of the inner product, and yeah, because $\theta$ is a function of the integrated variables, it would have to stay in the integral.